# zookeeper is not secure even using sasl authentification

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm configuring a kafka cluster with 3 nodes of brokers and 3 nodes of zookeeper I implemented the security as mentioned in the confluent documentation adding the attribute `authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider`
and 
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl

and added the `KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka/zookeeper_jaas.conf` to my systemd file.

but when I use zookeeper-cli from outside the cluster I can see znodes.

what I'm doing wrong

EDIT:

the config requireClientAuthScheme=sasl exit in my zookeeper properties file

P.S

the SSL and SASL weren't enabled. this may affect old znodes? do I need a migration ? to apply the security on old object created ?

Answer (score 0):

You need `requireClientAuthScheme=sasl` in zookeeper.properties, and `-Dzookeeper.requireClientAuthScheme=sasl` on the Zookeeper JVM command line.  And you also need to set `secureClientPort` and not `clientPort` in zookeeper.properties.

See the section "Require All Connections to use SASL Authentication" [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/zk-security.html#require-all-connections-to-use-sasl-authentication).

Comment: ``Environment="KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka/zookeeper_jaas.conf Dzookeeper.requireClientAuthScheme=sasl" `` 

exist in my systemd file

Comment: I've updated the answer then - are you setting `clientPort` in zookeeper.properties?  Specifying that will mean there is still a plaintext listener operating.

Comment: I disabled the clientPort and added secureClientPort  in my zookeeper.properties I got this error. 

``Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: clientPort is not set``
<br/>
I'm using confluent zip file

Comment: Actually, I can use zookeeper-cli to connect to my SECURED cluster but in READ mode only, I tried to execute ``rmr /borkers/topics``  I got authentication failure, thus as suggested by confluent you can use Network restriction if you don't want want to restrict access to zookeeper.

``secureClientPort`` unknow attribute when using the package from confluent